# MySQL long_query_time value

Tags: mysql, debugging, optimization, logging

I'm debugging a MySQL 5.1.61 database, and I have the `long_query_time` set in the `my.cnf` file to 10. Slow queries are being logged to a database table.

However, it's logging queries that take a fraction of a second.

In fact, my queries being logged are so fast, the `query_time` field in mysql shows "00:00:00" for every query logged. Even when I had them logging to a file, they showed query times in the range of "Query_time: 0.004763"

I know that my configuration file is being read, because all my other changes have worked.

From all the documentation I've read, `long_query_time` should be seconds. Is there something else I need to do for that setting to stick?

Answer (score 2):

Do those queries have indexes? If not, then that's probably why they're being logged.

> Before MySQL 4.1, if you also use --log-long-format when logging slow queries, queries that are not using indexes are logged as well. Starting with MySQL 4.1, logging of queries not using indexes for row lookups is enabled using the --log-queries-not-using-indexes option instead. The --log-long-format is deprecated as of MySQL 4.1, when --log-short-format was introduced, which causes less information to be logged. (The long log format is the default setting since version 4.1.) [(>>)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/slow-query-log.html)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just forgot to restart your Mysql after editing 'my.cnf' file?

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysqld restart
```

or

```
sudo service mysql restart
```